# Regex to capture a whole word only using egrep

Tags: regex, linux, shell, unix, grep

I am using egrep to look through scripts in our perforce NAS.

i am trying to find where we use RCP & RSH....The problem i have is that 1) I suck at REGEX; 2) i am picking up junk I am not interested in. For example if a file has the word strcpy..it picks up on RCP..or ownership..hits on RSH.

Obviously i am not interested in those, but I don't want to exclude lines based on the words ownership or strcpy...because they may be used in conjunction...and its not a complete list.

Here is my regex

```
 'ftp|rcp|rsh'
```

How can mod these to hit on FTP, but not SFTP...rcp but no strcpy, rsh but not ownership.....etc.?

So Things I would want to match.

```
ftp
`ftp`
/ftp/
"PUNCT"FTP"PUNCT"
```

Comment: Or just `egrep -w 'ftp|rsh|rcp'`

Comment: @tripleee: you should make this an answer.

Comment: @tripleee -w is only available on linux grep

Answer (score 8):

Maybe you need something like this:

`\b` < - this is the border of word

`\bpattern\b` <- this pattern will match only `pattern`, but not `otherbigpatternthatyounotneed`

Comment: hmmm....this does exactly what I asked...but then i realized there may be a different issue. If rcp is called as /usr/bin/rcp...so maybe i can do this with word border with punctuation allowed on bothsides?

Comment: Is there anything wrong with this? `'[^a-zA-Z0-9]\bftp\b[^a-zA-Z0-9]|[^a-zA-Z0-9]\brcp\b[^a-zA-Z0-9]|[^a-zA-Z0-9]\brsh\b[^a-zA-Z0-9]'`

Comment: @nitrobass24: `\b` works in this case, too. Just try it. You don't need all those negated character classes.

Comment: So It works on linux but not HP...is regex different? I figured it would be POSIX compatible.

Answer (score 6):

There are several metacharacters:

- `\b` word boundary
- `\<` word start
- `\>` word end

So, one possible regex is: `\<(ftp|rcp|rsh)\>`

Comment: So this does exactly what I am looking for. I wished i had noticed the second answer earlier. I have tested this and it works on Linux and Solaris...but is not working on HP-UX. Do you know what would be different about regexp on HP?

Comment: Might as well be possible that they are GNU extensions. Although I cannot find it mentioned in the info page of `grep`. Have you tried `-w` as suggested by [triplee](http://stackoverflow.com/users/874188/tripleee) in the comments?