# codeigniter - route all uri to one special uri except some cases

Tags: php, regex, codeigniter

I want all uri of my site route to one controller. Except The uri starting with home, admin, login or sigun_up will not route to that one controller. How would you do that?

I'm thinking some kind of reg ex, something like this

**$route["all link route to this controller, except uri starting with admin, login, home and sign_up"] = 'boss controller';**

Comment: What have you attempted to solve this?

Comment: tried but no luck. I tried various regex, they are messy right now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you cannot do negative routing.
But you can do this following way:

```
$route['(admin|login|home|sign_up)'] = "$1";
$route['(admin|login|home|sign_up)/(:any)'] = "$1/$2";
$route['(:any)'] = "boss_controller";
```

Comment: CI cascades those routing. So basically, with that code. when go to any uri within the site you will get double routing (ex: my_site.com/home will go boss controller then redirect to home controller.

Comment: @angry_kiwi you are wrong.It goes as ordering you writing.If it match it does not check rest routes.You can test this many way.example 1. if you write this way `$route['(admin|login|home|sign_up)'] = "$1";$route['(admin|login|home|sign_up)'] = "boss_controller";`  `my_site.com/home` will never goes to boss_controller. it will go to home controller as it matched first. example 2: you can write `die()` inside your `boss_controller` and hit `my_site.com/home` it will not go to `boss_controller` and redirect. if it does it would exit your code.hope you understand.

Comment: in theory you are right. But infact, you can see what I mean by add a visitor count hook. let it run at post-controller. Now with that route you provide, when you open any page or controller, the hook will count two visits, that mean it routes and re-route. Here is the simple hook class I used https://www.dropbox.com/s/ui1f1dgg33wd9zm/Traffic.php?dl=0

Comment: I have tested the code.that above routes function works as you want. And no `post_controller` hocks run twice for `my_site.com/home`. Even you can do lots of redirect with `redirect` function `post_controller` hocks execute once for the last controller because for others controller `post_controller` hooks cannot be called.

Comment: Check your `Traffic::monitor` function executes twice for any other reason may be `javascript ajax` and `javascript redirect`.I have tested the hook and it runs once not twice.

Comment: Thank you, I find out what script redirects my website.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not familiar with CodeIgniter but since CI supports regex in routering, you may use the regex `^\/(?!(admin\b)|login\b\/*|home\b\/*|sign_up\b\/*)[a-zA-Z0-9_\/]*/g` to grab anything but /admin /login /home or /sign_up.
Here's a demo you may have a look.

**Explain:**

`^\/` matches the starting `/` in the URI

`(?!(admin\b)|login\b\/*|home\b\/*|sign_up\b\/*)` is everything but not admin|login|home|sign_up, here `\b` "assert position at a word boundary (^\w|\w$|\W\w|\w\W)" which means you can use something like adminabc or loginxxx if you want, there will be matched correctly.

`[a-zA-Z0-9_\/]` this part is acceptable characters in your URI.

**Result:**

```
------Not passing-------
/admin
/login
/admin/xxx
/login/xxx
/home/xxx/login/xxx
/sign_up/xxx/login/xxx
--------passing---------
/
/admintest/xxx
/loginetest/xxx
/hometset/xxx
/sign_uptest/xxx
/others
/others/xxx/login/xxx
/others/xxx/others/xxx/ooo
```

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/cV6hO1/5)

Hope it helps.

Comment: I got error. Tried echo preg_match('^\/(?!(admin\b)|login\b\/*|home\b\/*|sign_up\b\/*)[a-zA-Z0-9_\/]*/g', 'asd');

Comment: @angry_kiwi I can get it work by `preg_match('/^\/(?!(admin\b)|login\b\/*|home\b\/*|sign_up\b\/*)[a-zA-Z0-9_\/]*/', '/adminabc', $matches);`

Comment: what does $match suppose to be?

Comment: @angry_kiwi It is the match result. If you don't need it, just remove it and preg_match will return 0 or 1. see preg_match mannual http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Comment: strange. I tried echo preg_match('/^\/(?!(admin\b)|login\b\/*|home\b\/*|sign_up\b\/*)[a-zA-Z0-9_\/]*/‌​', 'admin'); doesn't produce anything, no zero nor 1 result

Comment: @angry_kiwi I think it is not a good way to output preg_match() result. You should use a variable to store the return of preg_match(), You will definitely get 0 or 1. I tried on my laptop, in the echo preg_match() way you will see "1" for successful match like `preg_match('/^\/(?!(admin\b)|login\b\/*|home\b\/*|sign_up\b\/*)[a-zA-Z0-9_\/]*/‌‌​​', '/admin'); `,  "0" shows up when nothing matched.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70576/discussion-between-lution-and-angry-kiwi).

Answer (score 1):

According to the codeigniter [documentation](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html) you can use regex within the routes files, so in this particular case, pulling from another [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12515568/3629438) by knittl:

```
\b word boundary
\< word start
\> word end
```

We can use the word boundaries to set your words to ignore and then do an opposite regex for the other case.

Regex to grab all *but* admin, login, home, signup:

```
([^\<(admin|login|home|sign_up)\>+-])/g
```

Regex to grab *specifically* admin, login, home, and signup:

```
([\<(admin|login|home|sign_up)\>+-])
```

*Note the use of the `^` character to denote the inverse relationship.*

So the final route should look something like this:

```
//Typical Route
$route['products/([a-z]+)/(\d+)'] = "$1/id_$2";

//Custom Route to go TO the inverse
$route["base/([^\\<(admin|login|home|sign_up)\\>+-])/"] = "base/$1/";

//Custom Route to go TO admin/login/home/sign_up
$route["base/([\\<(admin|login|home|sign_up)\\>+-])/"] = "base/$1/";
```

Haven't tested it, but in theory it should work.

Comment: it's not working. echo preg_match("/([^\\<(admin|login|home|sign_up)\\>+-])/", 'asd'); produced 0